# Architecture for Client Side Apps

Tags: android, ios, html, wcf, c#-5.0

I need to write a client side application which communicates to a WCF service.
The app is actually targeted for multiple platforms.

1. Internet Browser.
2. Android.
3. iOS
4. Windows Phone.

The client side is rich on UI.. should contain animations and "fireworks"..

In the past, Flash used to be the generic 'Glue' to hold all that.
But These days, I keep seeing and reading about HTML5 hype..
I also heard and read a bit about Xamarin but will not dive into it before I get some confirmation that it can deliver what it promises.

So, My questions are as follows:

1. What would be the technology to use in order to develop client side?
   Html5 or Xamarin - or should I just stick to flash?
   do note - this is not a request for opinions - or in other words:
   I'm looking for answers of experienced developers who already done something like that and can tell me of a sure path to success.
2. Xamarin and visual studio - is it correct that this will allow me to develop everything on VS.2012/2013 IDE and will be able to output packages per OS?

Keep in mind I'm MS oriented dev.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you as an MS oriented dev elaborate about this new Internet Browser OS?

Comment: @greenapps I meant platform.. I fixed it in the question.

Comment: Platform? You would compare Internet Browser with Android? How?

Comment: @greenapps well.. in example: Candy-Crush.. works on browser, works on android, works on iOS.. its not like I'm asking about some place where no one has gone before :)

Comment: On Android I use several browsers. They are just apps. So you talk of something running in a browser on Android?

Comment: This question is really too vague and general - sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention candy crush.

The realistic answer in business today is simply **develop the iOS, Android, and anything else natively**. It's the only thing that really works.

**Trying to save a few dollars on 'cross-platform' is useless.**

For **2D or 2D games specifically**, you should use Unity3D, which is the overwhelming market dominator, currently, for games production.

In general there are any number of better-or-worse "cross-platform" things like xamarin, appcelerator, etc etc.

But the overwhelming factor in your project will be, you **need to forget about a server side and change to parse.com**. That time-saving will utterly overwhelm any "minor" decisions about what to program the different platforms with.

---

FYI Unity3D works with c#.  Android is Java.  iOS is objective-C.

Comment: hmm.. so - what will give me the option to write in C# and get packages for iOS, Android, Windows and Web? will that be Unity3d?

Comment: Hi GY, it's a basic of the industry that Unity3D works with c#, Android is Java, and iOS is objective-C.  There is no solution that works in objectiveC. You need to download Unity and just get a feel for it, make some basic apps in a few hours. Everyone needs to be able to do a little work in c# going forward.  It is extremely easy.  You could check out as a curiosity Unreal game engine, Appportable, and things like "appcelerator". Good luck!